# How do you change Sales path color in Experience (SF Community)?

Tags: css, lightning-community, theme-branding, salespath

I'm trying to change below standard salesforce color to match brand colors than native Salesforce colours (e.g. Wanting to have a different color to replace green here). I tried changing custom css theme classes (i.e. slds-path__item slds-is-complete), but it doesn't seem to change this standard SF colors.

[image]

Any workaround to achieve this in Salesforce experiences (Communities)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware the theming went quite so deep in Communities (AKA Experiences) but if there is official documentation on that keep pursuing that.

As an alternative, and it may require some detective work, but this **beta** feature documentation [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) suggests that things like the colors should be customizable:

> If you're working in Lightning Web Components (LWC) and Salesforce
> Lightning Design System (SLDS), styling hooks will enable
> customization for your Lightning components in an elegant and
> supported fashion.
>
> For the Winter '21 release, we are focusing exclusively on
> component-level customizations. Theming will be available in a future
> version.

Comment: Thanks @Keith C, yes this is the idea I'm going with. Doing the detective work :)